# How to use strtok()/strtok_r() to split a line

Tags: c, shell

I am using C to write a basic shell. The structure of the shell is pretty simple:

1. get input,
2. parse input,
3. exe the commemt.

To get the input, my professor requires to use `getline()`, so the type of return for my input is `char *`.
I pass the input to function `parse_input(line)` and use `strtok()` / `strtok_r()` to split the input. but I have problem here. I get null when I split. My professor requires me to use `strtok()` / `strtok_r()` to split. I have attached an image of my code here. I can split if I use `char[]` but here is `char*`. I don't know how to fix this.

```
char *parse_line(char *line){
    int index = 0;
    char *token;
    // char **tokens = malloc(buffs * sizeof(char*));
    
    //token = strtok_r(line,TOKEN_SPLIT,&line);
    token = strtok(line, TOKEN_SPLIT);
    printf("token: %s\n",token);
    while(token != NULL){
    // tokens[index++] = token;
    printf(" %s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, TOKEN_SPLIT);
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Don't use either `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` in a shell for splitting the command line — the functions destroy the delimiters, and you need to know what the delimiters are.  If you _must_ use them because of professorial diktat, then be aware that it means you'll have to write commands with spaces where a standard shell does not require them.  Consider `cat<file1>file2` — that will work in a normal. shell with no spaces, but your shell is unlikely to handle it well using `strtok()` etc.  (Generally, use `strtok_r()` and avoid `strtok()` altogether.)

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Images of code are hard to use. Code should be posted directly in your question *as text*.

Comment: Your function is always going to return `NULL` — you should probably be returning `tokens` (plural), but the return type of the function needs to change (and you need to be able to identify how many tokens are in the array with a count or a NULL pointer to terminate the list).  It might be better to return a structure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're allowed to make a shell that works differently, you know

Comment: @user253751: yes, you are.  But you need to be aware of the ramifications of the decisions you make.  Using `strtok_r()` is usually inappropriate — but since the professor says "thou shalt", the shell will have different rules from 'usual'.  Care will be required — should the shell handle `cat >file2` (no space between `>` and `file2`)?  Also, what about `echo " argument with spaces "`?  And so on.